# Activerecord associations build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I m working on a rails app.
With a record build there are some associations that are build simultaneously before building a record
using the .build method

**for example**
`records.each {|record| self.associations.build(name: record)}`

but this build one record per query

**Is there any way to build all in one query**??

PS : Dont want to do it with sql

Comment: `Is there any way to build all in one query?` what?

Comment: @emaillenin to build all the records in one sql query using activerecord.